# Retrieve all customers data

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, collection, customer-attribute

I want to retrieve all customer data including the address information, customer custom attributes, and customer profile information. Right now i'm using customer model like this:

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach ($collections as $collection) {
            $result[]= $collection->getData();
}
print_r($result);
```

form this i only get basic information like `entity_id`, `store_id`, `created_at`, `is_active`, and `etc`. by using this i can't get even the customer personal information like telephone or at least customer name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the customer details like below :

## customer id here

```
$customerId = 1;
```

## load customer object

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId); //insert cust ID
```

## create customer address array

```
$customerAddress = array();
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address)
{
   $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
}
```

## displaying the array

```
echo '<pre/>';print_r($customerAddress);exit;
```

After getting the user’s address you will see something like this:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 1
    [entity_type_id] => 2
    [attribute_set_id] => 0
    [increment_id] => 
    [parent_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2013-12-05 14:28:40
    [updated_at] => 2013-12-05 16:14:13
    [is_active] => 1
    [firstname] => Daniel
    [lastname] => Halmagean
    [city] => New York
    [region] => New Jersey
    [postcode] => 123123
    [country_id] => RO
    [telephone] => 2342423434243
    [region_id] => 282
    [street] => my street name
    [customer_id] => 1
)
```

Comment: And how to get all customer ids?!

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the default query for a customer collection. As you might notice without specifying fields to retrieve it retrieves everything. So lets add some fields!

   ```
   $collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('telephone')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', 'sander')
   ->addAttributeToSort('email', 'ASC');
    var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
   ```
2. In your case you just need to specify the addAttributeToSelect so it only retrieves that field. On non EAV collections use addFieldToSelect.

   ```
       $users = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

      foreach ($users as $user)
      var_dump($user->getData());
   ```